# MYSQL: How to check if values are not in certain time intervals

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am having the following problem. I am querying a call center database and I want to check for phone calls which are not answered.

I have a call entry timestamp (when the call has entered), call beginning timestamp (when an agent has answered the call) and a call end timestamp. If a call is answered and completed I will have values in all three of the columns. If a call is missed I will have values only in the call entry timestamp. There is also a column which states the status of the call if it is answered then it will say ANSWERED, if it is missed it will say ABANDONED.

My question is the following, how can I make such a query that will check if a call is missed / abandoned when an agent was not busy on another call. That means that I have to check the interval between all the call begining and call ending timestamps and exclude missed calls in this period. The result will be only the calls which have been missed when the agent was not busy.

The main table columns are as follows:

```
ID_agent
Caller_number
Entry_Time
Answer_Time
End_Time
Call_Duration
Call_Status
```

Answer (score 0):

For each agent, you are looking for the abandoned calls whose entry time does not fall between the answer time and end time of another call.

You can express this with a `left join` antipattern:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytabe t1
    on  t1.id_agent = t.id_agent
    and t.entry_time between t1.answer_time and t1.end_time
where 
    t.call_status = 'ABANDONED'
    and t1.id_agent is null
```

Or with a `not exists` condition:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.call_status = 'ABANDONED'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where 
            t1.id_agent = t.id_agent
            and t.entry_time between t1.answer_time and t1.end_time
    )
```